# How to deselect child nodes in JSTree after the user selected some nodes?

Tags: jquery, jstree

I would like to deselect some selected nodes in JSTree based on the user selection. If the user selected 2 child nodes with similar category. I would like to programmatically deselect the 1st node the user selected.

Thanks in advance for the help. Hope you can help me figure out the solution.

Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

You can place this testing into `select_node` event and see if you need to unselect something. E.g. the code below tests if there is more than one node selected and unselects the first one. Check demo - [codepen](http://codepen.io/ermakovnikolay/pen/WwOLyO).

```
.on('select_node.jstree', function(e, data){
      var countSelected = data.selected.length;
      if (countSelected>1) {
        data.instance.deselect_node( [ data.selected[0] ] );
      }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I think this can be helpful. However,this is not the exact answer that I need. I need to deselect some nodes but not all nodes based from certain criteria. Example if the node contains the word 'office' that selection will be deselected if the other selection contains the word 'office'

Comment: How do you pass that word to your script?

Comment: Perfect! This is what I was looking for to limit jstree selection. Thank you!